# Dynamically generate import in Python, specifically for a Django model

Tags: python, database, django, schema, models

Given a django Model, how could I auto-generate the valid import for it? I have a strictly internal  function (only devs will use it) that takes a model and returns some information on it. The problem is, I don't know how to dynamically import stuff:

For example, my app structure could be:

```
-myproject
    --books
    --music
```

And the function:

```
def my_func(Model):
    from appname.models import Model
    ## Rest of function here ##
```

Is there a way I could auto-generate the import based on the model? I was thinking accessing _meta attributes to get the app_label but obviously, one needs the import to access Model._meta. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of the Model argument? If it's already a model clearly you don't need to import anything again. If it's a string then you need to include the app name in the string, or you won't know where to import from. The import function is spelled `__import__` which is kind of ugly, but there you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `get_model` is what you need.

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
model = get_model('appname', 'ModelName')
```

Now you can do this.

```
objects = model.objects.all()
```

Comment: how do i access appname with a variable model name?

Comment: It is the name of the app in which the model is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically import modules using `importlib`, which allows you to specify a package as a second argument.

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module('modulename', 'packagename')
```

If you want the name of your module to match you model class, you could try this:

```
ModelClass.__name__
```

Comment: how can i access modulename?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__import__` function and pass in the model as a string.

```
def my_func(Model):
    modelVar = __import__("appname.models"+Model)
```

Comment: how can i access appname? won't it try importing from appname?

Comment: This will return the appname module, not the model I think. ISTR you need something more like this `__import__('appname.models', Model)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an update to Rag Sagar's answer. The location of `get_model` is different on the current django version (4.1, as of writing).

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> model = apps.get_model("app_label", "ModelName")
>>> model
<class 'app_label.models.ModelName'>
```

Or with alternative syntax:

```
>>> model = apps.get_model("app_label.modelname")    
>>> model
<class 'app_label.models.ModelName'>
```

Docs reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model